# php Notice: Undefined index: login in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 55

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I am getting warnings. I would like to take care of it. Here is the offending code

```
if ($_REQUEST['login']) $user = $_REQUEST['login'];
elseif ($_COOKIE['user']) $user = $_COOKIE['user'];

if ($_REQUEST['encpas']) $pass = $_REQUEST['encpas'];
elseif ($_COOKIE['pass']) $pass = $_COOKIE['pass'];

if ($_REQUEST['randsess']) $sess = $_REQUEST['randsess'];
elseif ($_COOKIE['sess']) $sess= $_COOKIE['sess'];
```

I am not sure how to get rid of them.

Thanks

Comment: `$_REQUEST['login']` isn't defined; the notice even gives you the line number

Comment: Always make sure the index exists before trying to do stuff with it.

Comment: Also since it seems you are relatively new to PHP development, I would highly recommend you not use $_REQUEST superglobal unless you really have cases where you might get a parameter passed via POST or GET.  I would imagine you are trying to process a POSTed login, so you should probably use $_POST as you probably don't want people to be able to append login credentials to your URL and have them work.

Comment: I am brand spanking new to PHP. Thanks. I am trying to work with an abandoned OpenSource PHP project. So the first task is to get it 2 work. Then update and modernize the code to today's specs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your variables to see if they set and have a value or not:

```
if ( isset($_REQUEST['login']) ) { 
    $user = $_REQUEST['login'];
} elseif ( isset($_COOKIE['user']) ) {
    $user = $_COOKIE['user'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using isset() to check if the index has been initialized before you check if it's true or not. 
http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use array_key_exists, or isset. The  last is faster according to some benchmarks.

```
if( isset( $_REQUEST['login'] ) ) {
  $user = $_REQUEST['login'];
}
```

isset doesn't count NULL as value.

Be careful with this because the following:

```
index.php?login=&otherstuff
```

Will set login with empty value. But it will be set.